# Running a few commands (that then ask questions) on startup

Tags: centos, command-line, rhel, startup, uwsgi

lets say I go to this file on linux CentOS to setup some startup commands

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

in this case lets say I want to startup uwsgi

so normally in the command line I might type something like this:

```
[linuxuser@localhost ~]$ systemctl start uwsgi
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'uwsgi.service'.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  admin Support (Administrator)
 2.  linuxuser (linuxuser)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 2
Password:
```

How would I put the identity and the password in the rc.local file in order to get uwsgi to run upon startup?

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# THIS FILE IS ADDED FOR COMPATIBILITY PURPOSES
#
# It is highly advisable to create own systemd services or udev rules
# to run scripts during boot instead of using this file.
#
# In contrast to previous versions due to parallel execution during boot
# this script will NOT be run after all other services.
#
# Please note that you must run 'chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local' to ensure
# that this script will be executed during boot.

touch /var/lock/subsys/local
systemctl start uwsgi
2
mypassword1$
```

I don't think that is right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants to authenticate because you're not root. So starting from rc.local will work as that runs as root. But this is not the way to go - uwsgi is a service so can just be set to start at bootup anyway:

```
sudo systemctl enable uwsgi.service
```